# Find closest point to a line

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Imagine a straight line through the origin.  Since rotations and 
reflections are easy, assume the slope is in the range 0 to 1.
We have a grid of the integer points in the cartesian plane.
I want to find the grid point greater than 0 and <= D the 
line passes closest to.

The simple approach is for each x from 1 .. D, find the point above and
below the line and calculate the perpendicular distance to the line.
This will take 2 x D comparisons to find the minimum.

That's not bad but I am trying to come up with a log(D) approach.
Is there one?

An equivalent problem would be to find the closest rational
number n / d where d <= D.

Comment: @Mark Ransom.  OK. Find the closest rational number that I have to rotate by.

Comment: Might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_approximations

Comment: Ignore my comments please, I misunderstood the question. My simplifications only lead to a linear solution which you already have.

Comment: @anatolyg That looks really promising

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `the grid point greater than 0 and <= D`?

Comment: @Alexey More precisely, 0 < x <= D and y ~ m * x, where m is slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to be equivalent to yours: [Finding the closest integer fraction to a given random real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385580/finding-the-closest-integer-fraction-to-a-given-random-real)

The accepted answer there uses a [Farey Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Also links to this [interesting blog post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/10/20/best-rational-approximation/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20TheEndeavour%20%28The%20Endeavour%29).

Comment: Doesn't guarantee log(D) but looks pretty good.

Comment: I coded this in C and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but an optimization in some cases: If the slope of the line is a rational number, then there will be repetition, allowing you to look at fewer points if D is larger than the denominator.

Eg: if the slope is 12/17, then you don't need to look at more than 17 points out from the origin. After that it will repeat.

Of course, if D < 17 in that example, it's no benefit.

Also, if your slope is `π`, you're out of luck...

Comment: As I said in the question, I'm trying to find a rational number.  Assume the slope is a floating point value.

Comment: @stark: This is just an optimization in the case when the slope *itself* can be expressed as a rational number, with the denominator less than D.