# Optimizing my guessing algorithm for number guesser

Tags: java, algorithm, math, optimization, random

I'm a relatively new coder learning Java, and my CompSci teacher assigned us something called a number guesser game, where you have to guess a random number. However, in assignment was a section on extra credit, where the user thinks of a number, and the computer has to guess what the number is in as few tries as possible.

Right now, my code for doing so looks something like this:

```java
public static void gamone() {
        System.out.println("Think of a number between 1 and anything- I'll try and guess it.");
        System.out.println("What is the end of the range?");
        double range = s.nextDouble();
        int guess, count=0, which = 0;
        double base = 0;
        String response;
        guess = (int) (range / 2.0);
            while (count < 15) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Is the number " + guess + "?");
                response = s.nextLine();
                response = response.toLowerCase();
                
                
                if (response.contains("yes")) {
                    System.out.println("I'm just that good, huh?");
                    break;
                }
                
                
                else if (response.contains("no")){  
                    System.out.println("Was is higher or lower?");
                    response = s.nextLine();
                    response = response.toLowerCase();

                    if (response.contains("h")) {
                        base = guess;
                    
                            guess = (int) ((range - guess) / 2.0) + guess;
                        
                    }else if (response.contains("l")) {
                        range = guess;

                            guess = guess - (int)((guess - base) / 2.0);

                    }
                    
                    
            }
        
        
        }
            System.out.println(count);
    }
```

I Understand the best way mathematically is to simply do what I did- to divide the difference by  2 and add or subtract that. However, is there a way I could use things like random numbers to actually make it better at guessing numbers?

Comment: I can't imagine that random guesses would improve things.  But I think your cause might be helped by recomputing the guess after a _lower_ guess as well as after a higher one.  Or better yet, just compute the next guess once at the top of the loop with `guess = base + (range - base)/2`.

Comment: Sorry, yea I had code to do that I just accidentally deleted it. It's in now- do you think there's any other way to improve it?

Comment: The answer is “no”: A binary search, as you have implemented, is the fastest way.

Comment: No, random won't help.  But if you code up https://stackoverflow.com/a/65009192/585411 in Java, your teacher may be impressed.

Comment: You could improve a little bit I think. If you guess x and it is lower, then the upper bound can be set to x - 1 and not just x and if it is higher the lower bound can be set to x + 1. Also I see no reason to use doubles, this can be done with integers only.