# Guessing a float value using binary search

Tags: algorithm, search, floating-point

I would like to write a program that guesses a number chosen by a person, by asking the person questions of the form "is your number greater than x?".

If the number is an integer of a limited size (say, 32 bits), then it is easy to guess using binary search - 32 questions are sufficient.

Now, suppose the person chooses a real number that is represented by a floating-point variable (e.g. `float` in C++, which also uses 32 bits). There are finitely-many possible values of a `float`, so my program should still be able to guess the exact float selected by the person using a small number of questions. But, I am not sure how to do it using binary search, since the possible values of a float are not evenly spaced.

Question: how can I guess a `float` value using a small number of questions of the form "is your number greater than x"?

To make the question more concrete, suppose you are given a function `bool is_greater_than(float x)`. How many calls to this function do you need in order to guess the number? Can it be done with only 32 calls?

Comment: The problem you're going to have is with oddball values like -0, and NAN. Your function `is_greater_than` won't let you distinguish between +0 and -0. NAN is not a comparable value.

Comment: @user3386109 OK, so let's assume the person is not allowed to choose these special numbers. This still leaves almost 2^32 "normal" numbers to choose from.

Comment: Then you proceed just as you would with integers. With integers, you're basically guessing one bit at a time, starting with the MSB. So with a float, you first guess the sign bit, then each bit of the exponent, and finally the bits of the mantissa. Easy to say, hard to do because you need to do the math to find the right values. For example, to determine the sign bit, you can't just ask, `is_greater_than(0)`, since what you really want is greater than or equal to 0 (for the sign bit to be 0). So you need to ask `is_greater_than( -epsilon )` where epsilon is the smallest possible magnitude.

Comment: Not exactly your question, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996100/binary-search-for-a-fraction/65009192#65009192 is an answer to an interesting variant. Given that all floats are rational numbers, it should produce an answer reasonably efficiently in your case.

Comment: Quite simply, at each step, choose x so that half the remaining floating-point numbers are greater than it and half are less than or equal to it.

Comment: There is code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48392678/298225) that tells you how many representable numbers are between two numbers. A function could be added to do the converse, return a number that is a certain number of representable numbers away from a starting number, and then doing a binary search is easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking sign you have to find exponent as soon as possible. For 32-bit floats there are 255 possible values of exponent (256th is reserved for special numbers). So at the first stage do binary search over exponent value. At most 8 steps (8 bits of exponent)

Then perform usual binary search with step halving to determine exact value of mantissa - at most 23 steps (23 bits of mantissa)

This approach allows to overcome `not evenly spaced` problem, but there is another one - user can (and almost definitely does) guess number without exact binary representation, so you have to use some epsylon tolerance (depending on exponent)

Comment: I read about exponential search, but it talks about searching in an array. How exactly can I apply it to reveal the exponent?

(For the second problem, let's assume that the user always picks a float with an exact binary representation).

Comment: first step - you give value 1. If larger - value 2, value 4, value 8 and so on. When you stop - for example, at 4096 - you do usual binary search at range 2048..4096. Note that you need at most 255 steps here - to decrease, you can make 8 steps over exponent. I think, it's better approach, will change the asnwer

Comment: The mantissa is always evenly spaced?

Comment: Yes, inside one binary range - from 0b000....01 to 0b1111...1111 for given exponent

Comment: sorry, from 0b1 000....01 to 0b1 111...1111  (due to hidden mantissa bit)

Comment: There are 254 exponent values, not 255 (from −126 to 127). The exponent field values 0 and 1 encode the same exponent value, −126. They differ in that 0 also encodes a 0 leading bit for the significand (not mantissa), and 1 encodes a leading 1 bit.

Comment: There is no need for any “epsylon tolerance” in this question.